# How Does The "Publicist" Badge Work?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I know a little box appears saying "Share this link! [link]", but share it where?  How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Share it in a social manner, eg. Facebook, Twitter, Friends, Blog, Digg, IM, ...

By doing that you are publishing the question to a public outside the StackExchange community.

As for how, just copy the link and paste it. Perhaps give it some explanation so it's more than a link...

---

**Announcer:** Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses in 3 days.

**Booster:** Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses in 4 days.

**Publicist:** Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days.

More info on badges [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges).

Comment: How is SE going to know you did that?

Comment: The link contains an identifier which can be used to identify you and thus reward you when enough visits have been made to your link.

Comment: Cool, so how many visits do I need?

Comment: Publicist is 1000 unique IP addresses in 5 days, listed them in my answer. :-)

Comment: I thought that meant the question was visited by that many *before* you shared the link, but your answer makes more sense. :)